# My IF CONTAINS formula won't work

Tags: process-builder, formula

I have a Process builder that adds the Organization name to a Description field on update of an Affiliation. I want it to not add the same name several times, so I tried to write a formula. But it keeps adding the same name..
I used this as a starting point:

```
IF((CONTAINS( My_Field__c,”Salesforce”)), false, true)
```

(Source: https://pritamshekhawat.wordpress.com/2015/07/31/salesforce-formula-with-contains-function-tips/)

And this became my formula:

```
IF(CONTAINS([npe5__Affiliation__c].npe5__Contact__r.Description,[npe5__Affiliation__c].npe5__Organization__r.Name),([npe5__Affiliation__c].npe5__Contact__r.Description & " " & [npe5__Affiliation__c].npe5__Organization__r.Name),[npe5__Affiliation__c].npe5__Contact__r.Description)
```

Explained: So, if the description field contains the Org name it should only add the existing description value.. If it does not contain the name, it should keep the existing value + add the org name.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just wrote it in wrong order .
So it should be :

```
IF(CONTAINS([npe5__Affiliation__c].npe5__Contact__r.Description,[npe5__Affiliation__c].npe5__Organization__r.Name),[npe5__Affiliation__c].npe5__Contact__r.Description,([npe5__Affiliation__c].npe5__Contact__r.Description & " " & [npe5__Affiliation__c].npe5__Organization__r.Name))
```

Comment: Wow, I thought I'd tried every combo by now, but apparently I missed one! Thank you!!

Comment: @MeretheAndersen Could you please mark this answer as the best answer if it helps you ?